# Start playing the audio after selecting card in results view

Tags: bixby

I'm trying to take the data (concept) from a card a user selects from a results view containing multiple cards and instead of presenting the information from that card in a more detailed view i'm trying to use the properties of the Concept the card displays, ie: Song author, title ... and transform that into a audioPlayer.AudioInfo concept and start playing the audio.

I am familiar with how the audio demo capsule plays audio, where the audioPlayer.AudioInfo is first build, an then passed to the audio player in the same action: https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/audio

```
action (PlaySessionOfDay) {
  type (Search)
  collect {
    computed-input (sessionToPlay) {
      description (Fetch the sessions to be played)
      type (audioPlayer.AudioInfo)
      min (Required) max (One)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: BuildSessionOfDayAudioInfo
        }
      }
      hidden
    }

    computed-input (session) {
      description (By passing in the AudioInfo object to the PlayAudio action, we ask the client to play our sound.)
      type (audioPlayer.Result)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: audioPlayer.PlayAudio
          value: $expr(sessionToPlay)
        }
      }
      hidden
    }
  }
  output (Result)
}
```

How an can you use the selected Song card from the list of cards as the input into the PlaySessionOfDay action and then pass it to an action like BuildSessionOfDayAudioInfo, to create an audioPlayer.AudioInfo.

It looks like you can't have compute block

```
compute {
        intent {
          goal: BuildSessionOfDayAudioInfo
        }
      }
```

unless you are using computed-input (sessionToPlay).

**Edit**: I think some of the trouble is because by default cards clicked on in a list-of (songs) view invoke a details view. Is there any way to avoid this and use the selected data as the input to an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any way to avoid this and use the selected data as the input to an action?
**Yes, set has-details (false) in your view model**, read more [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.render.list-of.has-details)

You need to add on-click with the intend **PlaySessionOfDay**
You would also need implement **PlaySessionOfDay** so it could take an input (I assume you have more than one content to play)